# Need help modifying progress bar - html/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have certain tasks/jobs running in the backend. I made a basic webpage which shows in-progress/completion status of those tasks. My webpage is being refreshed every few seconds and accordingly the new counters of the tasks/jobs completed are displayed.

[This Liquid bubble progress bar](https://codepen.io/junebug12851/pen/mJZNqN) have caught my attention too much and I want to replicate the same into my basic webpage.
But that one, waits for user to input a number in a text box and accordingly the progress bar changes.

I am looking to make it live indicator, i.e. without manually inputting a value into the text box.

I tried having a function which loads when the page is refreshed and input current completion status counter into that text box (example 22%), but seems there is no effect.

```js
function pbar() {
    document.getElementById("percent-box").value = "22";
}
```

Reading lines of the actual javascript indicated the bubble changes it value only when there is a keyup - if not it stays at the default value which is set at 67.

Please could I get some help to make the right javascript code and the right function calls to make that a live one. Thanks heaps in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the functionality in a **setProgressValue** function, which you can call at any time.

Great work by [June Hanabi](https://codepen.io/junebug12851) and [Jamie Dixon](https://codepen.io/JamieDixon/pen/Pqrjvv).

```js
function setProgressValue(val) {
  var colorInc = 100 / 3;
  var valOrig = val;
  val = 100 - val;

  if(valOrig == 0)
  {
    $("#percent-box").val(0);
    $(".progress .percent").text(0 + "%");
  }
  else $(".progress .percent").text(valOrig + "%");

  $(".progress").parent().removeClass();
  $(".progress .water").css("top", val + "%");

  if(valOrig < colorInc * 1)
    $(".progress").parent().addClass("red");
  else if(valOrig < colorInc * 2)
    $(".progress").parent().addClass("orange");
  else
    $(".progress").parent().addClass("green");
}

setProgressValue(80)

setTimeout(()=>{setProgressValue(42)}, 2000)

setTimeout(()=>{setProgressValue(27)}, 4000)

setTimeout(()=>{setProgressValue(93)}, 6000)

setTimeout(()=>{setProgressValue(67)}, 8000)
```

```css
.wrapper > div {
  transform: scale(.5);
}

*{box-sizing:border-box}body,html{height:100%}body{background-color:#1a1a1a;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:15px;color:#ccc}.wrapper{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:box;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;-o-box-align:center;align-items:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;-o-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-o-box-orient:vertical;flex-direction:column;height:100%}.green{margin-top:15px}.green .progress,.orange .progress,.red .progress{position:relative;border-radius:50%}.green .progress,.orange .progress,.red .progress{width:250px;height:250px}.green .progress{border:5px solid #53fc53}.green .progress{box-shadow:0 0 20px #029502}.green .progress,.orange .progress,.red .progress{-webkit-transition:all 1s ease;transition:all 1s ease}.green .progress .inner,.orange .progress .inner,.red .progress .inner{position:absolute;overflow:hidden;z-index:2;border-radius:50%}.green .progress .inner,.orange .progress .inner,.red .progress .inner{width:240px;height:240px}.green .progress .inner,.orange .progress .inner,.red .progress .inner{border:5px solid #1a1a1a}.green .progress .inner,.orange .progress .inner,.red .progress .inner{-webkit-transition:all 1s ease;transition:all 1s ease}.green .progress .inner .water,.orange .progress .inner .water,.red .progress .inner .water{position:absolute;z-index:1;width:200%;height:200%;left:-50%;border-radius:40%;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-iteration-count:infinite;-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;animation-timing-function:linear;-webkit-animation-name:spin;animation-name:spin}.green .progress .inner .water{top:25%}.green .progress .inner .water{background:rgba(83,252,83,.5)}.green .progress .inner .water,.orange .progress .inner .water,.red .progress .inner .water{-webkit-transition:all 1s ease;transition:all 1s ease}.green .progress .inner .water,.orange .progress .inner .water,.red .progress .inner .water{-webkit-animation-duration:10s;animation-duration:10s}.green .progress .inner .water{box-shadow:0 0 20px #03bc03}.green .progress .inner .glare,.orange .progress .inner .glare,.red .progress .inner .glare{position:absolute;top:-120%;left:-120%;z-index:5;width:200%;height:200%;-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg);border-radius:50%}.green .progress .inner .glare,.orange .progress .inner .glare,.red .progress .inner .glare{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.15)}.green .progress .inner .glare,.orange .progress .inner .glare,.red .progress .inner .glare{-webkit-transition:all 1s ease;transition:all 1s ease}.green .progress .inner .percent,.orange .progress .inner .percent,.red .progress .inner .percent{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;font-weight:700;text-align:center}.green .progress .inner .percent,.orange .progress .inner .percent,.red .progress .inner .percent{line-height:240px;font-size:92.3076923076923px}.green .progress .inner .percent{color:#03c603}.green .progress .inner .percent{text-shadow:0 0 10px #029502}.green .progress .inner .percent,.orange .progress .inner .percent,.red .progress .inner .percent{-webkit-transition:all 1s ease;transition:all 1s ease}.red{margin-top:15px}.red .progress{border:5px solid #ed3b3b}.red .progress{box-shadow:0 0 20px #7a0b0b}.red .progress .inner .water{top:75%}.red .progress .inner .water{background:rgba(237,59,59,.5)}.red .progress .inner .water{box-shadow:0 0 20px #9b0e0e}.red .progress .inner .percent{color:#a30f0f}.red .progress .inner .percent{text-shadow:0 0 10px #7a0b0b}.orange{margin-top:15px}.orange .progress{border:5px solid #f07c3e}.orange .progress{box-shadow:0 0 20px #7e320a}.orange .progress .inner .water{top:50%}.orange .progress .inner .water{background:rgba(240,124,62,.5)}.orange .progress .inner .water{box-shadow:0 0 20px #a0400c}.orange .progress .inner .percent{color:#a8430d}.orange .progress .inner .percent{text-shadow:0 0 10px #7e320a}@-webkit-keyframes spin{from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes spin{from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="green">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="percent"><span>67</span>%</div>
        <div class="water"></div>
        <div class="glare"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @alotropico, appreciate your help, I will give this a try.
Is there a way to add more color classes to that script please if you could show me how to add one new color i will replicate it to my needs. Currently it only has red, orange and green.

Comment: Sorry, the javascript part would be very easy but the css is quite heavy for this and it was made with stylus (like sass and less, a preprocessor for css), it would be a lot of work to add just one color in the final css, as green, orange and red appear 24 times each, and it wouldn't be useful for you, because you'll have to do it all over again for each color. You can check it out in the original example, it's quite easy to add a color there (using stylus to generate the css), each one appears only once

Comment: understood, this is out of my brain's capacity :) 
thanks @alotropico :)

Comment: hi @alotropico, is there a way to change the size of the bubble please? like reducing it to 50% of its original size.

Comment: I just were around. Sure, just add .wrapper > div {transform: scale(.5);} to the css.. i added it at the beginning in the answer ;)

Comment: Feel free to check the answer as accepted if it worked for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222474/discussion-between-shashi123-and-alotropico).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a promise. I've included documentation is the example below. It would avoid refreshing the whole page.

```js
let promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  // Resolve the promise after 1 second
  // Replace this with an AJAX call to get the values from the server
  setTimeout(() => resolve("22"), 1000);
});

promise.then(
  // Change the value with what the promise returned
  result => {
    let content = document.getElementById("percent-box");
    content.innerHTML = result;
  },
  // In case of an error show an alert
  error => alert("error")
);
```

```html
<div id="percent-box">10</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Gerard, as my html page (sometimes) is like 5MB I definitely need the thing which can avoid refreshing whole webpage and get only the necessary latest contents...please could you help me a bit more on this. Thanks in advance.